when i create a lookupup field then the lookup field is created but when i try to select the value then the value is not been selected
i create a new Group Module in vtiger CRM - 8.1.0  when i create a lookup field in other modules with group module then the lookup field is created but when i try to select the value then the value is not been selected . //i create a lookup field from the below code
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Program');
$block = Vtiger_Block::getInstance('LBL_PROGRAM_INFORMATION', $moduleInstance);

$field = Vtiger_Field::getInstance('groupid', $moduleInstance);

if(!$field){
    $field  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field->name = 'groupid';
    $field->label= 'Group No';
    $field->uitype= 10;
    $field->column = $field->name;
    $field->table = 'vtiger_program';
    $field->columntype = 'INT(11)';
    $field->typeofdata = 'I~O';
    $block->addField($field);
    $field->setRelatedModules(Array('Group'));
} 

